# How to do **override** in F# module-function structure? (or similar effect)

Tags: f#

lets say I have these code--

```
let plus a b=Seq.init a (fun _->1)|>Seq.fold(+)b
let multiply a b=Seq.init a (fun _->b)|>Seq.fold plus 0
let power a b=Seq.init b (fun _->a)|>Seq.fold multiply 1
```

How to do it if later I want plus another way--

```
let shortPlus=(+)
```

Well, I considered some solutions...

The first is to duplicate whole code, but what if a code is really huge?

```
let shortPlus=(+)
let multiply a b=Seq.init a (fun _->b)|>Seq.fold shortPlus 0
let power a b=Seq.init b (fun _->a)|>Seq.fold multiply 1
```

The second is send the plus function as a parameter later customizable--

```
let customizablePlus f a b=f a b
let customizableMultiply plus a b=customizablePlus plus|>fun plus->Seq.init a (fun _->b)|>Seq.fold plus 0
let customizablePower plus a b=customizableMultiply plus|>fun multiply->Seq.init b (fun _->a)|>Seq.fold multiply 1
let shortPlus=(+)
let power2=customizablePower shortPlus
```

but -- why should Power take care multiply how to do plus? Why calling power need to tell it how to do plus? It's unnatural!

Well the third *guess* is-- use the *add code file as shortcut* ability of VisualStudio-- I will try it a bit later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't override functions like you can methods in C#. But your power function does not depend on plus in the first version, so you don't need to pass it, it just needs multiply function.

```
let plus1 = (+)
let plus2 a b = plus1 a b |> (+) 1
let customizableMultiply plus a b = Seq.init a (fun _-> b)|>Seq.fold plus 0
let customizablePower multiply a b= Seq.init b (fun _->a)|>Seq.fold multiply 1
let mult1 = customizableMultiply plus1
let mult2 = customizableMultiply plus2
let power1=customizablePower mult1 2 3 //=8
let power2=customizablePower mult2 2 3 //=27
```

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, I'm trying this method now~ Hmm, unsure is there some problem will encounter.